# Trying to write a function that uses a session variable

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to write a function that takes the current user's username (as either a session variable or a GET or POST parameter) and displays private content (id and filepath) that this user can view because it's shared with a group to which this user belongs. Here's what I have so far, but I seem to be a bit stuck in getting it to run. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
session_start();
include "dbconnect.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT filepath, id FROM Content WHERE username = '$username' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $username=$row['username'];
    echo $username;
}
?>
```

Comment: Explain the problem? I know what you're trying to achieve but It's not clear what aspect of your code is failing.

Comment: I'm unsure if I used the session variable correctly to take the user's username

Comment: try adding `var_dump($_SESSION['username']);` or `var_dump($_SESSION);` to your code after `session_start();` to review the contents of your session.

Comment: @sql_injector I guess based on your chosen username that we are to assume that you are already aware that this code is also flawed because it contains a potential SQL injection vulnerability...?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT filepath, id FROM Content WHERE username = '$username' ";
```

If you don't also `SELECT ... username` then `$row['username']` would not be expected to contain a value.  You only have `filepath` and `id` in your `SELECT` list.  Other values from the row are not returned, even if they appear else where in the query (e.g. simply using `WHERE c1 ...` or `JOIN ... ON c1 ...` will not cause the value from column `c1` to be returned).